# Is it possible to add "Reviewers" through a Github pull request template

Tags: templates, github

In the github web ui, in a pull request, I can click to add "Reviewers".  I am wondering if there is a way to add these through the pull request templates, so I don't have to manually do it every time; if so how?

Bonus, is there a way to add an "Assignee", "Labels", or "Projects"?

Answer (score 4):

While you will not able to add a reviewer using a [pull request template](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request-template-for-your-repository/) you could /cc someone in the template to alert them to the pull request.

Another strategy to consider would be to use [webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/). You could use the [pull request event webhook](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pullrequestevent) to alert you when a pull request has been opened.  From there, you could create a small script that then assigns a reviewer using the [create a review request](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/review_requests/#create-a-review-request) API endpoint, whenever the webhook's payload shows that a pull request has been opened.